# Where to find Salesforce Training?

Tags: training

Is there any online site or platform where I can learn how to work with Salesforce available ?

Comment: Do you mean for development or learning to use the salesforce CRM applications (sales cloud, service cloud, marketing cloud,.. ) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try starting with the [workbooks](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_workbook). There's plenty of examples on there covering a lot of different topics.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you are after, but here are some options which will get you started..

- Salesforce Help - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTHome
- Salesforce Docs - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs
- Success Community https://success.salesforce.com/
- Developer Community https://developer.salesforce.com/

and finally you can get your own Salesforce Environment to learn and practice what you learn..

- to get your own Developer Org you can [register here](https://developer.salesforce.com/en/signup?d=70130000000td6N)

Answer (score 0):

Trialhead is also a more recent addition to training available:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead