# Good Place To Start

Tags: training

I've got a new member on my team who has no clue what salesforce is and is not technical. Where would you start with grooming a person like this to be a salesforce ninja?

Comment: The [SalesForce Workbooks](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_workbook) would be a good place to start learning about SalesForce.

Comment: chk this discussion which has few links to get started - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50361/where-to-find-salesforce-training/50381#50381

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce just launched Trailhead which is getting really great reviews for this exact purpose:

https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead

Comment: totally for about trailhead already it's a nice little site